Пользовательские команды (user install) не отображаться discord.py
Решил попробовать сделать бота доступным везде (User Install), сделал как нужно при помощи tree.command(). В итоге на серверах где есть бот все работает, а уже в ЛС и других серверах нет. Как исправить?
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord import app_commands
from tokenpy import TOKEN

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=None, intents=None)
group = app_commands.Group(name="action", description="действия")

@group.command(name="hug", description="Обнять пользователя")
@app_commands.user_install()
async def _hug(interaction: discord.Interaction, member: discord.Member):
    await interaction.response.send_message(f'{interaction.user.mention} обнял {member.mention} <3')

@group.command(name="kiss", description="Поцеловать")
async def _kiss(interaction: discord.Interaction, member: discord.Member):
    await interaction.response.send_message(f'{interaction.user.mention} Поцеловал {member.mention} ❤')

@group.command(name="sosi", description="Соснуть")
@app_commands.user_install()
async def _sosi(interaction: discord.Interaction, member: discord.Member):
    await interaction.response.send_message(f'{interaction.user.mention} Соснул у {member.mention} ')

@group.command(name="hit", description="Ударить")
@app_commands.user_install()
async def _hit(interaction: discord.Interaction, member: discord.Member):
    await interaction.response.send_message(f'{interaction.user.mention} ударил {member.mention} ❤')

@group.command(name="send", description="Отправить сообщения")
@app_commands.user_install()
async def _send(interaction: discord.Interaction, mesg: str):
    await interaction.response.send_message(f'{mesg}')

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    await bot.tree.sync()

bot.tree.add_command(group)
bot.run(TOKEN)

discord.py последней версии, user install включен

